# How can I pass a TYPE COLLECTION parameter to a stored procedure in JPA?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, plsql, persistence

I have the next Collection Type defined in the DB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TORDEN_CAMPO" AS VARRAY (5) OF VARCHAR2 (9)
```

Now, I need call this stored procedure that have two parameters of TORDEN_CAMPO type:

```
    PROCEDURE BUSQUEDA(pivTABLA                  IN VARCHAR2,
                   ...(Parameters)
                   pivPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL   IN NUMBER,
                   pivCUENTA                 IN VARCHAR2,
                   pivENTIDAD                IN VARCHAR2,
                   pivMACRO                  IN VARCHAR2,
                   pivDEPENDENCIA            IN VARCHAR2,
                   pivIdPARTIC               IN VARCHAR2,
                   ...(More parameters...)
                   pivORDEN_CAMPO            IN tORDEN_CAMPO,
                   pivORDEN_TIPO             IN tORDEN_CAMPO,
                   ...(Moooore parameters...)
                   xmlFinal                  OUT XMLTYPE);
```

Well, in Java JPA I have this code to mapping the procedure:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "BUSQUEDA",
    procedureName = "PKG_CONSULTA_TRAZABILIDAD.BUSQUEDA",
    parameters = {
       ...(Parameters)
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivPERIODO_EVENTO_INICIAL", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivCUENTA", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivENTIDAD", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivMACRO", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivDEPENDENCIA", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivIdPARTIC", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        ...(More parameters...)
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivORDEN_CAMPO", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String[].class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="pivORDEN_TIPO", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String[].class),
        ...(Moooooooore parameters...)
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="xmlFinal", mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = String.class)
    })
```

When I do the call I have the next error:

> ```
> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
> ```
>
> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
>   Error Code: 17004
>   Call: BEGIN PKG_CONSULTA_TRAZABILIDAD.BUSQUEDA(pivTABLA=>?, pivIFGD=>?, pivPERIODO_INICIAL=>?, pivPERIODO_FINAL=>?, pivPERIODO_EVENTO_INICIAL=>?, pivPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL=>?, pivCUENTA=>?, pivENTIDAD=>?, pivMACRO=>?, pivDEPENDENCIA=>?, pivIdPARTIC=>?, pivNifCliente=>?, pivNombCliente=>?, pivNifGrupo=>?, pivNombGrupo=>?, pivCODA=>?, pivDiferida=>?, pivTI=>?, pivFiltroAnulaciON=>?, pivORDEN_CAMPO=>?, pivORDEN_TIPO=>?, pinREG_INICIAL=>?, pinREG_FINAL=>?, xmlFinal=>?); END;
>       bind => [24 parameters bound]
>   Query: ResultSetMappingQuery()
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.execute(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:220)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ResultSetMappingQuery.java:312)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
>       ... 30 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10495)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10799)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:6097)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:241)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2441)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(Oracle9Platform.java:525)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:797)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
>       ... 44 more

I think that this error is by the array that I want pass, all the rest of params are Strings or Number... so that how I can pass this VARRAY by JPA?